# Java Mission Control - which methods are spending time on socket I/O?

Tags: java, performance-testing

I can see the CPU time spent on various methods and I can see the time spent on socket I/O. I see that the application is bottlenecked on Socket Reads.

But where can I see WHICH methods are doing all of that I/O?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For JMC 5.x, there are stacktraces for the Socket events in I/O -> Socket Read -> Socket Read Trace Tree.
For JMC 6/7, the stacktraces are shown in the stacktrace view when you go to the Socket I/O page.